# Database class, a data access object can't use a method of the database class

Tags: php, database, function, database-connection

I created database class and a database access object so I can somehow Implement a value object pattern.

Here is some part of the database class and it's function:

```
class Database {

    protected $conn = null;
    private $stmt;


    // create a connection
    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $passwd) {
        try {
            // mysql and pdo
            $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd); 
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->get_error($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Part of this db class is function I created called `num_rows`

```
public function num_rows($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    if ($this->stmt) {
        $this->stmt->execute();
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }
}
```

I also have this DAO class that does what you can actually see.

```
class Dao {
    protected $db = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $dbh = new Database('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=doorche', 'root', '');
         $this->db = $dbh->getConnection();
    }
//put your code here
}
```

When I extend the DAO class in another class for example a `loginDao` I can't somehow access the *num_rows*

Why is that happening?

Comment: because Dao did not extends Database class..

Comment: call `parent::__construct();` in `loginDao` constructor

Comment: i called the parent::__construct() ofcourse, but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You need to `inherit Dao` class as below.

```
class Dao extends Database {
```

then in `loginDao` .

```
class loginDao extends Dao {
```

now `loginDao` can access `Database` methods too,

Comment: did I really need to extend the database class in DAO? or no? I already instantiated it..

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito i can not see you extended it...you have `class Dao {` in your question...

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito what you are doing in `Dao construct` method is **creating object of Database.**

Comment: yes I created an object and used it to get the connection.. I don't see a reason to extend it if I already created the object, and another thing is that I tried what you are saying but it fail and throws the same error

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito thats right so create global object so Dao child class also access it..